# REGEX to extract string between spaces

Tags: regex

I'm new in regex, first time I use them.
Given a string, with multiple words, I need to extract the second word (word = any number of char between to spaces).

```
For example: "hi baby you're my love"
```

I need to extract "`baby`"

I think I could start from this: `(\b\w*\b)` that matches every single word, but I don't know how to make it skip the first match.

Comment: to get "baby" you can do `b\w*\y` .though i couldn't get what you mean't by *but I don't know how to make if skip the first match.*

Comment: Can you try `(?<=.)(\b\w+\b)` ?

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Answer (score 5):

Thank's for suggestion guys,
I've modified a little your regex and I finally find what I need:

```
(?<=\s)(.*?)(?=\s)
```

This one `(?<=.)(\b\w+\b)` was also kinda good but fails if I have string like "hi ba-by you're my love" splitting "ba-by" into "ba" and "by".

Comment: this will match spaces between spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even without `\b`.
Use `\w+\s+(\w+)` and read the word from capturing group 1.

The regex above:

- First mathes a non-empty sequence of *word characters* (the first word).
- Then it matches a non-empty sequence of *white chars* (spaces) between
  word 1 and 2.
- And finally, the capturing group captures just the second word.

Note that `\s+(\w+)` is wrong, because the source string can begin with a space
and in such case this regex would have catched the **first** word.